# Is there a better way to make a button that changes an attribute in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, button

I'd like to make a button on a view page that changes an attribute in my database. I know how to do it via a form (but we don't want to do that) and I have used a convoluted ajax method to do it (which is just overly complicated), but it seems like there has got to be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope (to a better way).

Q: How do you change a value in the database?

A: You have to send a[n] HTTP request to your server.

What are your options for sending HTTP requests to a server?

1. Submitting a form and having the server respond with a new view.
2. An asynchronous Javascript call with either XML or JSON (AJAX or AJAS)

You could write your own Javascript to do the "AJAX", or your would just use what's already out there.

Comment: David, one more question, I'd like to use the button_to method to do this, and it appears to be making a form that is just a button, but the button is trying to direct me to a page rather than simply direct me to a function. Do you know what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: There's a Rails guide on using AJAX with Rails: [http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ajax_on_rails.html](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ajax_on_rails.html).  You need: `:remote => true`